# EF SqlQuery always passes parameter with null value to my stored procedure with multiple parameter requirements

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm having issue using EF `SqlQuery` with a stored procedure and its multiple required parameters. I looked everywhere and I have the write code because if I use an inline query. It works.

Here's the code

```
string callSP = "ListDirectoryMember @Country,@Lastname,@State,@Phonecd,@City,@Spec,@Zip,@Language";

var Member = await _db.Database.SqlQuery<MemberInfo>(callSP,
            //new object[]
            //{
                new SqlParameter("Lastname", string.IsNullOrEmpty(lname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : lname + "%"),
                new SqlParameter("Phonecd",string.IsNullOrEmpty(areacode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : "(" + areacode + ")%"),
                new SqlParameter("State", string.IsNullOrEmpty(statecd) ? (object)DBNull.Value : statecd ),
                new SqlParameter("City",string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ? (object)DBNull.Value : city),
                new SqlParameter("Zip",string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) ? (object)DBNull.Value : zip),
                new SqlParameter("country",string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ? (object)DBNull.Value : country),
                new SqlParameter("Language",string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) ? (object)DBNull.Value : language),
                new SqlParameter("Spec",string.IsNullOrEmpty(spec) ? (object)DBNull.Value : spec)
            //}
    ).ToListAsync();
```

If I use an inline query it works, but with the stored procedure, the result is just like I'm passing null values to all parameters even though it has values.

What am I missing? The reason for this is our main database belongs to our vendor and all read and write access to their Oracle database is through stored procedures.

I used the stored procedure with `exec` keyword too - same result. Just no filtering

```
    string query = "Select col1,col2 from sometable where " +
            "(mem.POSTAL_CD LIKE @zip  or @zip is null) " +
            "AND " +
            "(mem.LAST_NM LIKE @LastName or @LastName is null) " +
            "AND " +
            "(mem.PHONENUM LIKE @PhoneCd or @PhoneCd is null) " +
            ............
```

That is the same query in my stored procedure.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What happens if you add `@` before your parameter name when you're initializing the different `SqlParameters()`?

Comment: actually the original question have `@` because I tried both with and without works with inline.

Comment: Did you try passing the string as: " EXEC ...... @..... and calling with: _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand? Another trick you can use to debug this is enable your SQL Profiler, so you can see the query that was triggered by EF.

Comment: yes sir..tried that too.I was able to run it..check the answer below..But I'm not comfortable with it..I know there's a way better and neater solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with different syntax I was able to make it work.It doesn't look nice though. Is sql injection possible here?

```
    string callSP = "ListDirectoryMember @Country = {0},@Lastname = {1},@State = {2},@Phonecd = {3},@City = {4},@Spec = {5},@Zip = {6},@Language = {7}";


        var Member = await _db.Database.SqlQuery<MemberInfo>(callSP,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ? (object)DBNull.Value : country,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(lname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : lname + "%",
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(statecd) ? (object)DBNull.Value : statecd,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(areacode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : "(" + areacode + ")%",
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ? (object)DBNull.Value : city,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(spec) ? (object)DBNull.Value : spec,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) ? (object)DBNull.Value : zip,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) ? (object)DBNull.Value : language



            ).ToListAsync();
```

thank you so much for looking at my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may just have some logic errors here. Take for example this line:

```
new SqlParameter("@Phonecd",string.IsNullOrEmpty(areacode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : statecd),
```

You're checking if `areacode` has a value and if it does, you're setting the param to `statecd`, which doesn't seem right. Or this one:

```
new SqlParameter("@State", string.IsNullOrEmpty(statecd) ? (object)DBNull.Value : "(" + areacode + ")%"),
```

Where you're checking if `statecd` has a value, but then setting the parameter to a string composed using `areacode`. It's possible you're just getting null values where you don't expect them to be because you're testing for the wrong things in the wrong places.

Comment: oh yeah..i forgot to edit my question..i saw that already..but unfortunately..it is still the same..good catch though